# PhpStorm - Navigate to method

Tags: ide, keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm

In a class, I quickly want to navigate to, let's say, the indexAction method. In SublimeText I could press cmd + R, type 'inde', and hit enter on the dropdown that shows all the results from my search.

I haven't found this in PhpStorm, is this functionality available?

Comment: **Ctrl+Click** ... or `Navigate | Declaration / Implementation` ?

Comment: Nope, that's the navigation to the definition. I updated my question to be more precise. But thanks for answering though ;)

Comment: Under `Navigate` menu: File, Class, Symbol. If you are inside that file/class already -- `Navigate | File Structure` (once again -- all under `Navigate` menu)

Comment: Sorry, saw CrazyCoder's answer first. But thanks anyways!

Answer (score 119, accepted):

`Navigate` | `Symbol...` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> in the default keymap on Windows/Linux, <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> with Mac OS X keymap, <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> in Mac OS X 10.5+ keymap).

`Help` | `Find Action`, type `symbol` to see shortcut in your keymap.

The above works globally across the project, **for the current file only** use `Navigate` | `File Structure` (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> on Mac OS X 10.5+) and start typing the method name to narrow down the results, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to navigate to the selected method.

Related help sections:

- [Navigating to Class, File or Symbol by Name](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html)
- [Navigating with Structure Views](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/navigating-with-structure-views.html)

Comment: Just to point out an insufficiency: As of version 7.1.3, you can't filter by class name **and** method name at the same time. If you're looking for a method that exists in plenty in your project, you'll have to wait.

Comment: IMO this behavior is sub-optimal compared to Sublime Text or Text Mate. There is no quick way to jump between symbols in the same file. The "File Structure" menu is not filterable, and the other navigation tools work only globally.

Comment: @aaronbauman It seems to work like sublime text in phpstorm 8 at least. The box that pops up for Navigate > File Structure allows you to just start typing and it will filter the results: http://ctrlv.in/517640

Comment: I did manage to find that popup, which will accept typing, but not paste text. So, better than nothing, but still sub-optimal.

Answer (score 34):

I also do this in **Sublime Text** with <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and then look for the method via `@`.

I think the closest way of doing this in **PhpStorm 8 & 9** is using the

<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> (perhaps <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> in **Windows**)

which lists all the methods in the current class and then type the name of the method to navigate to it.

**OPTIONAL / SUPPLEMENTARY**

To avoid confusion from switching to `Sublime Text` and back to `PhpStorm` I decided to bind it <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> that way I won't have to adjust again.

In `PhpStorm` there is an easy way to see if there is a conflict with your keybinding so I decided to migrate my `Sublime Text` shortcuts to `PhpStorm` instead of the other way around.

Under `PhpStorm > Preferences > Keymap` you would see a button just beside the search field and check if your command has a conflict in our case we want to bind <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> to <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to just try that key stroke if it's bound to other command.

Otherwise bind it to `Main Menu > Navigate > File Structure`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: for Ubuntu CTRL + F12

Answer (score 8):

Please see the screenshot and find out the shortcut key for your OS.
[image: PHPStorm Menu bar > Navigate dropdown]